# Result displays only one record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

it’s me again! The problem I had with my code is that it displays only one record instead of two. I already tried echoing the SQL statement and pasted on PHPMyAdmin and shows 2 records but on my end it doesn't.

Here’s my controller:

```
function index()
{
    if($this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()):
        $data['title'] = 'Tes : Home';
        $data['record'] = $this->Profile_model->get_profile_by_id();


        $ws = $this->Wall_model->get_user_posts();
        foreach($ws as $w):


             $data['cont'] = '<li class="profile-thread-post"> 
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td width="75" class="valign-top">
                <div id="post-avatar">
                <img src="../../images/avatar.gif" width="74" height="74" />
                </div>
                </td>
                <td width="15">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="valign-top">

                        <div id="post-div">
                            <div>';
                $data['cont'] .= '<span class="title oswald blue cap">'.$w->fname.'</span><span class="title oswald red cap">'.$w->lname.'</span>';
    $data['cont'] .= '<p>'.$w->body.'</p>';
    $data['cont'] .= '<br/><br />
  <div class="floatLeft small-text grayLight">
   Posted 2 hours ago
  </div>

  <div class="social-links alignRight">

  </div>
 </div>';
                $pid = $w->id;
            $comments = $this->Wall_model->get_user_comments($pid);
            //if(count($comments) > 0 ):
            $data['cont'] .= '<ul id="post-comments-div">';
                foreach($comments as $c):
                    $data['cont'] .= '<li class="comment-entry">
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td class="valign-top comment-avatar alignLeft" width="55">
      <img src="../../images/avatar.gif" width="46" height="46" />
     </td>
     <td class="valign-top comment-post">
      <div>
       <span class="sub-title oswald blue cap">'.$c->fname.'</span><span class="sub-title oswald red cap">'.$c->lname.'</span>
      </div>
      <div class="small-text-11 comment-content">'.$c->comment;
    $data['cont'] .= '</div>
      <div class="comments-meta alignRight">
       <span class="lgray small-text">Posted 2 hours ago</span>
       <a href="#" class="uline like-link ">like</a> &nbsp;
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </li>';
                endforeach;
                $data['cont'] .= '</ul>';
            //endif;
                $data['cont'] .= '</td></tr></table></li>';   
        endforeach;

        $this->load->view('profile/index', $data);
    else:
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', '<div class="error centerText">You are not logged in</div>');
        redirect('auth/login');
    endif;
}
```

Here's my model:

```
function get_user_posts()
{
    $uid = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id(); 

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT a.*, b.* from user_profiles a inner join user_statuses b on a.user_id = b.user_id where b.user_id = $uid order by posted_date DESC");

    return $query->result();
}

function get_user_comments($pid)
{
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user_statuses a 
                                INNER JOIN user_status_comments c ON a.id = c.post_id 
                                INNER JOIN user_profiles b ON b.user_id = c.user_id where a.id = $pid");



    return $result->result();
}
```

On my table the SQL statement shows
|user_id|post_id|body|
   1       1      S
   1       2      H

Comment: Try select count(*) to see how many records are being selected

Comment: what happens when you do a `var_dump($ws)` before you enter your loop? Still 1 record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$data['cont'] = '';
//then foreach loop
foreach($ws as $w):
//then
$data['cont'] .= '<li class="profile-thread-post">...
```

Comment: Sorry I can't have a vote up for this I'm still new. . . Great though!